# RHEL7 kickstart fails to install product certificate

Tags: kickstart, rhel7

I am installing Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.0 Sever from a customized image with a Kickstart file. After rebooting, no product certificate has been installed, making it impossible to register the system.

I assume that I have inadvertently removed something from the install image that is necessary for creating this certificate file, but I am unable to figure out what.

After install:

```
# subscription-manager list
No installed products to list
# ls -l /etc/pki/product
total 0
```

I expected there to be a 69.pem file there, but none has been installed.

This is the kickstart file I am using currently (I've removed a lot of stuff from my original one, this one still causes the problem):

```
%packages
@core
httpd
lm_sensors
%end

%post
systemctl enable httpd.service
%end

reboot
```

I have also removed several packages from the Packages sub-directory, so it is entirely possible that one of the necessary packages might be missing. I've posted a full file list from the image on http://pastebin.com/M7bidk1G. All the files are taken from the original `rhel-server-7.0-x86_64-dvd.iso` file.

*WORKAROUND:* This is caused by us modifying the repo database on the ISO image (for adding our own RPMs), which somehow made Anaconda not identify the image as proper. I've added this workaround in the kickstart script:

```
cp /mnt/repodata/productid /etc/pki/product/69.pem
```

Comment: have you tried with subscription-manager subscribe ?

Comment: Yes, subscribing is fine, attaching a license is fine, but I cannot activate any product since it thinks I haven't installed any. My kickstart image is probably missing some vital piece that sets this up, as a clean minimal install off the official DVD gives me the correct certificate and has `subscription-manager list` display valid data.